# Materials and Textures not Showing Up in GLSL Shading Mode

Tags: game-engine, shaders

I understand that in the Blender Game Engine, the GLSL shading mode is generally suggested, because it renders real-time shadows, and it renders per pixel instead of per vertex like in the Multitexture shading mode.  I noticed that when I switch to the GLSL shading mode, materials, and textures don't show up in the internal player, and it appears as if all materials have been set to shadeless.  If I use the Standalone Player button, it displays all the materials and textures properly.  I'm curious if there is a setting that I should have checked, or if it is normal for this to happen.  Also, once I package my game, will it appear as if it's running in the Standalone Player, or the internal player?  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the Viewport Shading to 'Textured' should help with this.  'Material' also works.
It sounds like you may be using 'Solid' mode.

[image]

Comment: I find it interesting that the Embedded Player display will be different depending on the viewport shading.  I guess it makes it easier to debug in different situations.  Thanks so much for you help!